# Error 404 script not working, if

Tags: php, .htaccess

My error404 script was working perfectly, but then I did this:

I had non-friendly URL's like this:

```
localhost/website/user.php?name=UserA
```

Then, I updated my `.htaccess`

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/?$   user.php?name=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404 /website/error404.html
```

After this, my URL's are friendly URL like this: `localhost/website/UserA`

But, the error404 script do not work When the page is something like this: `localhost/website/dsfdsfsfasfsfsfs`

But if the page is something like this: `localhost/website/SomeThingHere/sdfsfs`

Comment: Try putting the RewriteRule below the Conditions and above the error document.

Comment: @TimvanUum Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Z-]+)/?$   user.php?name=$1    [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /website/error404.html
```

With `RewriteCond` before `RewriteRule`

But you rewrite `/website/dsfdsfsfasfsfsfs` to `user.php?name=dsfdsfsfasfsfsfs`
You need to change `user.php` to show 404 error when the user does not exist